# call from an array with an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, get

i want to call from an array using the get array but it doesn't work what is the correct way to format this?

```
if(isset($_GET["category"])){
    $cat = 'SELECT DISTINCT `Category` FROM `products`';
    $result = $mysqli->query($cat);
    $i='0';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $i++;
        $Category = $row["Category"];
        $id = array($i => $Category);
    }
    $result->close();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category="'. $id[$_GET["category"]]. '" ORDER BY Code';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you made a mistake inside the loop. If you want to assign a value to an array key, you need to replace this:

```
$id = array($i => $Category);
```

with this:

```
$id[$i] = $Category;
```

Otherwise `$id` would always be a new array only with the current key-value pair.

Comment: works strange i was using the instructions from the php manual: [function array](http://nc.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

Comment: In every loop iteration you had created a new array, which replaced the previous value of `$id`. So at the end you had only the key-value pair that the loop generated at last. BTW, you can use the [var_dump](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function to display the content of a variable. Do this after the while-loop (`var_dump($id);`) with the old and the new version and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

your query is wrong. use

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE Category='". $id[$_GET["category"]]. "' ORDER BY Code";
```

The `order by` clause must be after the `where` clause.